# How to keep list of Excel combobox always expanded while typing

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

How can I keep the list of Excel activeX combobox always expanded?

While I type I see this:

[image]

But after typing a letter "a" I want to see this:

[image]

Comment: I have found I can do it with VBA `ComboBox1.DropDown`. However I do not know how to roll back the list with VBA (disappear it).